# homeomorphism between a projective space and a line bundle

Tags: general-topology, continuity, vector-bundles

Take $\mathbb{R}P^{n-1}\hookrightarrow\mathbb{R}P^{n+k}$ as embedding on the last $n$ coordinates and take a point $l=[x_0:\ldots : x_k:y_1:\ldots :y_n]\in\mathbb{R}P^{n+k}-\mathbb{R}P^{n-1}$.

We define a map $\pi: \mathbb{R}P^{n+k}-\mathbb{R}P^{n-1}\hookrightarrow\mathbb{R}P^k$ by sending $l$ to $[x_1:\ldots :x_k]$. So $l$ is a line in $\mathbb{R}^{n+k+1}$ and $\pi(l)$ is a line in $\mathbb{R}^{k+1}$. Now we specify a functional $\pi(l)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by sending $(x_0,\ldots ,x_k)\mapsto y_1$. Likewise we obtain $n$ functionals on $\pi(l)$ via formulas
$$(x_0,\ldots ,x_k)\mapsto y_1, \ \ \ \ldots  \ \ \ (x_0,\ldots ,x_k)\mapsto y_n.$$

Finally we get continuous map $\mathbb{R}P^{n+k}-\mathbb{R}P^{n-1}\rightarrow nL^*$.

And I should check that this is the homeomorphism.

First of all to get a bijection we probably should get $(x_0,\ldots ,x_k)\mapsto y_i$ in some unique way, which I don't see.

Assuming that above is true and that multiplying all $x_i$'s and $y_i$'s by $\lambda$ gives rise to the same functional we obtain continuous bijection.
But why the inverse is also continuous?

Comment: Please check the formatting on your definition of $\pi$ -- it appears to make no sense. And when you write $y_1$, what do you mean? Does $y_1$ here stand for "some formula you're supposed to invent"? Because the letter $y$ has not previously appeared.

Comment: I corrected the typo. $y_i$ are last $n$ coordinates in $l$ - it is all what I have.

Comment: Is there any problem with $y$? I mean, likewise $x_i$'s, $y_j$'s are just used to describe a point $l$.

Comment: I have no idea -- I just tried to read the initial problem and it (typographically) made no sense. I won't actually be attempting to answer it; it's a bit outside my range of things-easy-to-answer. I'm pretty sure it's used as an example in Milnor and Stasheff's Characteristic Classes, albeit with slightly different notation, so if I wanted the answer, that's where I'd look...but that's only because that's the book most familiar to me.

Comment: Ok, I thought that $nL$ means $n$-tensor of $L$, but then dimensions were wrong, so I found that $nL$ is $\oplus$-product. Since we look on $\pi(l)$ like on the line in $\mathbb{R}^{k+1}$ mapping into $y_1$ is just linear map, so it's unique obviously. I left with the problem how to show that our composition is the bijection indeed, namely how to construct the inverse map: $nL^*\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{n-k} -\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$.